# Django: get the current domain(http_host) from signals

Tags: django

I am sending a mail with different confirmation links from different signals. These mails contain a link that the recipient has to click. If I am sending the link from www.example.com the confirmation link looks something like www.example.com/confirmation.

At the moment I am hard coding the domain name inside my settings file but maybe there is a better way more flexible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard [sites contrib app](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#getting-the-current-domain-for-display)

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use the site framework just to get domain name you can use the get_host function with request object.
domain_name = request.get_host()
but remember that this function return also the port use when requesting the page, So you can have domain.com:8000 for example

Comment: can't access `request` in signal